# How does PHPMailer reference posted data from HTML form?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have an HTML form which, when submitted by the user, will call a php file to mail me the form contents. I'd like to use PHPMailer, but I'm wondering how PHPMailer references form data. Is is the same as normal PHP and I'd just use `$_POST['inputName']`?

Comment: have you not downloaded their package?

Comment: http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/UsefulTutorial

Comment: @Fred Coming from JavaScript, which has many libraries that all change syntax and how things are referenced, I pondered that PHP could be the same. Also, the wiki, which I read before asking the question, doesn't mention anything about form data within HTML. It just shows how to add HTML to the PHP code.

Comment: I guess they figure we already know how to setup the syntax. Have a look at their examples, see if this helps => http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examples

Comment: The above links are long obsolete - [PHPMailer now lives on github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) including examples, wiki and other docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use that, it is same since *PHPMailer is also made in PHP*

Comment: That's what I figured. Stupid question, but I'm somewhat new to PHP and didn't see any references to that in the PHPMailer wiki. Thanks!

Comment: @BrianTucker: No fault for the new comers to php and you are welcome